# What is an example of a `storage_name` in decl_storage

Tags: rust, substrate

It says that [`decl_storage!`](https://crates.parity.io/srml_support_procedural/macro.decl_storage.html) is a "procedural macro" used for storing data to make it available in subsequent blocks.

At that link there's a sentence that says *Basic storage consists of a **name** and a type*. It then shows the different supported types, including the most basic supported type, which just contains a "Value" that appears to correspond to the **"storage name"** of `Foo`. This [line of the "Example" module of the SRML](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/srml/example/src/lib.rs#L271) also matches this pattern.

It then shows how the hashing algorithms are used to hash a combination of values, including the `storage_name`. The `storage_name` that's shown appears to correspond to a **"storage name"** such a `Foo` that was shown earlier on that page.

Then there's a sentence that says *Basic storage can be extended as such:*, it shows a pattern `... #name ...`, and describes it as `#name: Name of the storage item, used as a prefix in storage.`, which appears to correspond to a **"storage name"** such as `Foo` that was shown earlier on the page, and both `#name` and `#type` are not labelled as `[optional]` because they are not "extensions" to basic storage, that are fundamental to basic storage

Is `Foo` supposed to be an example of a `storage_name` that may be used with decl_storage!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `Foo` is an example of a storage name that can be used in decl_storage!.

All rust ident should be usable as a storage name in decl_storage I think.

(Indeed the documentation is mixing example and definition, sometimes using `u32` sometimes `type` for example)